# What is the difference between these two subsets in Discrete Math?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $U = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, x, y, \{1, 2\}, \{1, 2, 3, 4\}, \{1, 2, 3\}\}$

$A = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$

Can anyone explain to me the difference between these 2 pairs of things?

$$A\subseteq U \text{ and } \{A\} \subseteq U $$

And how come $\{A\}$ is not an element of $U$?

Thanks

Comment: One is a question if A itself is a subset of U, i.e. all elements of A are in U, the other is as to if the set containing as its only element A is a subset of U, i.e. is $A\in U$?

Comment: @anorton: You messed up the braces on $\{A\}$, and I can't fix it or suggest the edit because of the minimum character limit on edits.

Comment: In line 5 I've changed $A$ back to $\{A\}$ which I think is what you want - please let me know if not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The statement $A\subseteq U$ means that every element of $A$ is an element of $U$: in this case, $1,2,3,4$ are all in $U$: **true**, they are the first four elements in your listing.

The statement $\{A\}\subseteq U$ means that every element of $\{A\}$ is in $U$: that is, $A$ itself (not the *elements* of $A$) is in $U$: that is, $\{1,2,3,4\}$ is in $U$.  This is also **true** as $\{1,2,3,4\}$ is the second last element you have listed in $U$.  Notice however that this statement is different from the previous one: to confirm that one was true you had to look at the first four elements of $U$, not the second last.

However, $\{A\}\in U$ means that the *whole expression* $\{A\}$ is an element of $U$: that is, $\{\{1,2,3,4\}\}$ is an element of $U$.  This is **false**: if you look carefully at $U$ you will see that its elements are
$$1,\,2,\,3,\,4,\,5,\,6,\,x,\,y,\,\{1,2\},\,\{1,2,3,4\},\,\{1,2,3\}\ ,$$
and none of these is identical with $\{\{1,2,3,4\}\}$.

---

If it helps, think of a set as a bag containing stuff.  The bag $U$ contains the items $1,2,3,4$; it also contains a bag containing "duplicate copies of" $1,2,3,4$; but it does not contain a bag containing a bag containing $1,2,3,4$.

Comment: thanks, i was mainly confused with the {A} part because i wasn't sure if it was {{1,2,3,4}} or just {1,2,3,4} since my Grimaldi textbook is vague and doens't explain.

Comment: Wait a minute, the way you described the first one for {A} is a subset U kinda sounds like the same thing as describing A is an element of U?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly the same... but not the same as saying $\{A\}$ is an element of $U$.